# Locating information on grandparents?

Tags: united-states, military-records

I have the birthday, death date, burial place, spouses, children, and even military records, but I still can not locate any information on my grandpa or grandmas past information. I don't know where else to look for records (after checking FamilySearch, ancestry, findagrave, ect)

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  Something we need to be careful about with a question like yours is that we must observe our [privacy policy](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) because there would seem to be a good chance that they were born less than 100 years ago .  If you can perhaps [edit] your question to include the years (as a range) in which they were born and died, and the US state, but no identifying details, then the options for trying to help you may become clearer.

Comment: Also, your question is very broad because you do not say specifically what the main question you want to answer is.  Is it perhaps where to find the birth record of your grandfather (that would probably give you his parents' names)?

Comment: If you could give us more information provided it doesn't break any privacy laws I can have a look for you. If you know when they were married, why not order the marriage certificate. I'm in the UK so I don't know what kind of laws or the availability is in the US.

Comment: Likewise, welcome to G&FH.SE.  I agree that the question as written is far too broad.  You don't say what information you were looking for, how you attempted to search, or what your sources are for all the information you are starting with. Without a time frame, it's impossible to know if the reason you can't find things is because of privacy laws, or that the information you want is not online.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH.SE, Danny.  In the USA, we don't have tidy nationwide registration of births, marriages, and deaths comparable to the GRO indexes.  Most records are held at the local level, so working any genealogical problem involves knowing where people lived.  The rules for what information is available to the public and what is shielded by privacy laws are different for every state, which is why we would like to know what states are involved.

Answer (score 2):

Have you

- interviewed your parents, aunts, uncles, cousins for clues and memories?
- checked at family residences for documents like birth certificates, passports, funeral cards, etc.?
- searched in newspapers for obituaries, marriage announcements, family events, reports from county courts?
- searched creatively, using wildcards (for mis-spelled or mis-transcribed names) and date ranges and keywords?
- searched in image-only databases, like many probate files?
- created a time-line of family residence (county level if not actual addresses) to help locate where official records may be held?